# Vim — running external command bound to F5 to run Python script results in error

Tags: python, vim

I added the following to my .vimrc file:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F5>!python %
```

That should run the current file in Python when I press F5. Instead, it gives the following error:

```
Trackback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 349, in f_with_update
  File "<string>", line 358, in run_this file
NameError: global name 'send' is not defined
Press Enter or type command to continue
```

If I re-mapped F5 manually everytime I run VIM, this command works:

```
:map <silent> <F5>!python %
```

I don't recall mapping anything to F5, and my .vimrc file doesn't contain any mapper.
Any idea what's happening?

Comment: @romainl: That works. Please post it as answer so I can mark it so. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<F5>` is probably mapped elsewhere. Try `:verbose nmap <F5>` to see where.

Comment: Thank you. I knew what plugin is mapping <F5> (it's ipy.vim).

Answer (score 6):

```
nnoremap <silent> <F5>!python %
```

Maps `<F5>!python` to `%`. What you want is this:

```
nnoremap <silent> <F5> :!python %<CR>
```

Normal maps require `:` if you want to use a normal cmd-line command and you need to end it with `<CR>` to execute the command. Consider everything on the right hand side to be keys you would otherwise type in yourself.

You may find [this vim wiki page on python](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Python_-_check_syntax_and_run_script) useful.